# CSS: A background-blend-mode fallback for iPhone Safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari, background-blend-mode

I'm susccesfully using background-blend-mode on my header here: https://yogrow.co/ecommerce-stack

However I've noticed that the background-blend-mode is not working on iPhone. I just get no background color.

Here is the CSS I am using

```
background-repeat: repeat;
background-image: url("assets/img/swirl_pattern.png");
background-color: #E33551;
background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

Is the only / best option to use media queries to create a new set of css rules or is there an alternative way to have a fallback so for devices like iPhone Safari that do not show the color bg the background goes to a red.

Because I have white text on top of the background it currently looks illegible on the iPhone safari.

Thanks

Comment: I've been running into the same problem. I have found that `background-repeat: repeat;` causes the blend mode to stop working on iOS. I don't know why, but if you set it to no-repeat, then it works. Obviously that isn't an ideal solution though.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this tip. it fixed the problem i encountered.

Answer (score 19):

It seems like background-blend-mode not working with `background-repeat: repeat;`. Try to set `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

Comment: Yes. Rule background-repeat: no-repeat; helped me

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following modes is not supported by safari for background-blend-mode:
hugh, saturation,color and luminosity

I see the author of the question did not use one of the above mentioned, but it might help someone else.

Comment: That applies to `mix-blend-mode` not `background-blend-mode`

Comment: Can you please share any link regarding the not supported items for mix-blend-mode?

Comment: I believe `darken` doesnt work either. Atleast on `mix-blend-mode`

Answer (score 0):

`background-repeat: no-repeat` worked for me, but in our application, the element in question could sometimes have a repeating background, so that solution was not sufficient.  I found (in iOS 10.2) that any element with `border-style` set on it would not respect `background-blend-mode`; i.e., images and colors would not blend.  Removing `border-style` (or any variants like `border-bottom-style` or `border`) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely needed `background-repeat` in my design. I have a transparent PNG over a solid color (a linear-gradient layer).

The workaround isn't exactly pretty: I load [UAParser.js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js), and test for (iOS && WebKit).

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/UAParser.js/0.7.21/ua-parser.min.js'></script>
<script>
window.workaroundBackgroundBlendMode = (function() {
  var ua = UAParser()
  var isWebKit = (ua.engine.name === "WebKit")
  var isIOS = (ua.os.name === "iOS")
  var debug = false //|| true
  var shouldActivate = (isWebKit && isIOS) || debug;

  if (shouldActivate) {
    document.body.classList.add("is-ios-webkit")
  }

  // You can inspect this returned object afterwards
  return {isWebKit, isIOS, debug, shouldActivate, ua}
})()
</script>
```

There will be a small lag, but I figure this is justified because it only affects the buggy clients.